# Error in vector lengths in matlab but i checked them with length() and theyre equal

Tags: matlab, plot, vector

```
l1=length(A)
l2=length(L)
%Residual
V=A*X-L
S= (V'*P*V)/(6-2);
%adjusted values
Z=V+L

%plot of observed valued of y
plot(X,L)
%plot of adjusted value of Y
plot(X,Z);

%Covariance  Matrices for all Given Quantities can be Obtained by:
Cov_X= S*inv(N)
Cov_La=S*(A*N*A')
Cov_V= S*(inv(P)-A*inv(N)*A')
```

the output is

> > HA01

l1 =

```
 6
```

l2 =

```
 6
```

V =

-16.7888
-31.4848
110.0764
-3.8431
-51.1036
-6.8562

Z =

1.0e+03 *

```
0.9685
1.0886
1.2161
1.2905
1.3390
1.4506
```

Error using plot
Vectors must be the same length.

Error in HA01 (line 24)
plot(X,L)

i expected i accidently created different sized vectors etc but length are same yet it refuses to plot. please help i need to submit this in couple of hours.

Comment: You don’t show what either `X` or `L` are. Please read [mre].

Answer (score 2):

`length` will tell you how many elements its has, but not its shape.
If you do `size(X)` and `size(L)` you will likely see that one is, say, `1x6` and the other one `6x1`. Transpose one of them so they are the same `size`, not the same `length`.